# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Android Enthusiasts breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 11         28
Users destroyed                                 150          0
Users deleted                                     9          0
Users contacted                                  30          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           616      1,816
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               72         91
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        133      2,703
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue              160      1,661
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue             1,280      3,141
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              696      1,415
Tags merged                                       3          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             3          0
Tag synonyms created                              3          0
Questions unprotected                             2          1
Questions reopened                               64          0
Questions protected                               7        339
Questions migrated                               16          0
Questions merged                                  3          0
Questions flagged⁴                               57      1,900
Questions closed                              1,858        115
Question flags handled⁴                         956      1,001
Posts unlocked                                    0          3
Posts undeleted                                  18         69
Posts locked                                      9        443
Posts deleted⁵                                2,550      5,535
Posts bumped                                      0      8,729
Escalations to the CM team                        1          0
Comments undeleted                               69          0
Comments flagged                                  3        863
Comments deleted⁶                             1,435      2,406
Comment flags handled                           278        588
Bounties canceled                                 1          0
Answers flagged                                 216      5,698
Answer flags handled                          5,112        802
All comments on a post moved to chat              9          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://android.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...